# Asp.Net Session expires immediately

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-config

My Asp.net Session Expires immediately even though i did the settings in web.config file,

```
<system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="2880" mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies"></sessionState>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
        <trace enabled="false" localOnly="false"/>
        <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
        <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never" enableViewStateMac="false" />
    </system.web>
```

i did above settings in web.config even then it expires after approx 3 minutes...
can anyone help me??

Comment: How did you set the settings in the web.config?Can you show us some code what you did?

Comment: What date and time is it on the server?

Comment: i have pasted the code which i used above in <system.web> tags.. do reply if you have the answer..

Comment: Its UTC date and time on server..

Comment: Is it the _correct_ date and time?

Comment: http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/07/21/in-proc-session-state-management.aspx

Comment: Look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11375003/779408). I had this problem and its solution solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [cookieless](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) attribute if your application is AJAX-Enabled. Use default value of `cookieless` attribute.

From MSDN doc:

> The cookieless attribute can be one of the following possible values.
>   The default is the UseCookies value.
>
> Note:     When you configure an
>   AJAX-enabled ASP.NET Web site, use only the default value of
>   UseCookies for the cookieless attribute. Settings that use cookies
>   encoded in the URL are not supported by the ASP.NET AJAX client script
>   libraries.

Comment: yes i have used cookieless="UseCookies" in <sessionstate> tag.. so what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe session does not expire immediately, but simply die. Since you are using `InProc` session state it could die whilst

- Any change to the web.config file cause AppDomain unload and session as well
- Application Pool restart. InProc session satte pretty risky thing, I would suggest at least allocating separate Applciation Pool for each web-site
- Any code changes in code behind files cause AppDomain unload (and session as well) in order to load new assemblies in a new AppDomain

The best solution - use [SqlServer Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) session state.

Comment: i cannot use sqlserverto store session state i don't have access to admin rights of online sql server, i need to do it by other means..

Comment: @Puneesh - is it hosting company? You can ask to setup this feature for you. At elast ask whether your site has own app pool

Comment: SQL Server isn't necessarily the "best" solution. It's the most robust solution. I would go for State Server mode at the minimum though, and that doesn't need a SQL Server to host it.