# Why asp.net session is expired sooner than its timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, timeout

I have an Asp.net webservice. It has method M1. M1 creates a folder for each session. When a session is expired, I delete that folder in global.asax using the following code.

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirMyPacksFolder = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Utilities.getMyPacksFolder(Session));
            //dirMyPacksFolder.Parent.CreateSubdirectory("ended_" + Session.SessionID);
            if (dirMyPacksFolder.Exists)
            {
                dirMyPacksFolder.Delete(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.logException("", ex);
        }
    }
```

When I open my webservice in browser and call M1, it operates correctly and the folder is deleted on timeout expiration time that I have set. But when I submit "Invoke" button of webservice for the second time (after session timeout and folder is deleted), its session **starts** (create folder) and **ends** (deletes folder) **immediately before timeout that I have set.**

**Why this happens?**

If I open a new window (new session) for each method call everything is OK. But I have problem when I click "Invoke" button for second time. It is something like caching problem for same sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](http://www.thecodeking.co.uk/2011/08/why-sessionend-is-sometimes-called.html), I believe your problem may be similar:

- Client sends a cookie with a Session Id for an expired session
- Server creates a new session, reusing the id sent by the client
- If the request does not access session, the session is immediately abandoned.

Does your WebMethod actually access Session state?  If not, try adding an access to a dummy session variable.

**Update:**

These lines of code in **Global.asax** solve the problem:

```
 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Session["dummy"] = "dummy session for solving immediate session expire";
 }
```

**Update 2**

Personally I wouldn't do the directory creation in Session_Start; instead I'd have a method called something like `EnsureMyPacksFolder` which the app is required to call before any attempt to access the folder.  This would look something like the following, avoids the need for a "dummy" Session variable, and means the folder is only created if and when it is actually needed.

Global.asax:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // No code needed in Session_Start
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["MyPacksFolder"] != null)
    {
        // Folder has been created, delete it
        // ... add code to delete folder as above
    }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
public static void EnsureMyPacksFolder()
{
    if (Session["MyPacksFolder"] == null)
    {
        // Add code to create MyPacksFolder that was previously in Session_Start

        Session["MyPacksFolder"] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you use `Session_Start` and `Session_End` for ***Count*** users ? 

I use WebFarm, sessionsate mode SqlServer. 

Any source code samplefull?

Link not found, use http://thecodeking.co.uk/article/asp-net-session-end-event-fires-immediately-after%20session-start-resolved/

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following to your WebMethods?

```
[WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
```

Comment: yes I did. If I open a new window for each method call everything is OK. But I have problem when I click "Invoke" button for second time.

Comment: It is something like caching problem for same sessions.

Comment: are sessions not managed by cookies? What is your cookie expire duration

Comment: How can I check that and what is other options?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating and deleting folder under your web service path, iis immediatly restarts. Take a look on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248825/asp-net-restarts-when-a-folder-is-created-renamed-or-deleted).

Comment: I know this. No I am creating folders outside of application's main folder. And I have tested and know that Application_End is not triggered.

Comment: You also need enable session on client code.. Just try to write a client application (not test on browser) and assign cookie container to it. http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin47.htm